# Problem creating CentOS box with Chef Test Kitchen script

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox, centos6

I do have this kitchen.yml:

```
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: centos65
    driver:
      box: learningchef/centos65
      box_url: learningchef/centos65

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
    attributes:
```

I run:

```
kitchen create default-centos65
```

But I get error:

```
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
>>>>>>     Failed to complete #create action: [Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox ----
STDOUT: Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ...
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.20
    default: VirtualBox Version: 6.1
==> default: Setting hostname...
STDERR: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

hostname -F /etc/hostname

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

hostname: can't open `/etc/hostname'
---- End output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox ----
Ran vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox returned 1] on default-centos65
>>>>>> ----------------------
```

I am running Vargant and VirtualBox on my Windows10 lapotop. I have seen similar posts also on stackoverflow but I could not find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test kitchen fails to install VirtualBox Guest Additions 4.3.28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307099/test-kitchen-fails-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-4-3-28)

Answer (score 0):

ok, doing some more research I've found the answer here:

[Test kitchen fails to install VirtualBox Guest Additions 4.3.28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307099/test-kitchen-fails-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-4-3-28)